# tinyMCE strips “role” attribute from div tag

Tags: html, tinymce

I have html as below after entering the code into TinyMCE then role attribute is getting strip only in IE 11. Whereas in Mozilla it loads fine.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" role="author">
....
</div>
```

Wherever role attribute is there it is getting removed.

Comment: Can somebody please check

Comment: It is fixed by changing IE browser compatibility settings.